# Wait for timeout or event being set for asyncio.Event

Tags: python, events, python-asyncio

I have a class with a method that looks like this:

```
# self.stop_event -> threading.Event
def run(self):
    while not self.stop_event.wait(3):  # i.e. repeat every 3 sec
        pass  # do stuff
```

The idea is that several of these are run in their own thread and at some point one thread does `stop_event.set()`, which naturally stops all others. I want to switch to asyncio for this, because the tasks in `run` are mostly sleeping and doing IO. Thus, I got to:

```
# self.stop_event -> asyncio.Event
async def run(self):
    while not self.stop_event.is_set():
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        pass  # do stuff
```

The problem is that the `asyncio.Event` cannot be waited on, so when it is set, there are at most 3 seconds to wait before the method completes. This is a problem, because the sleep time may be minutes. Currently, I am working around this by wrapping the `run` in an `asyncio.Task` and then cancelling it like `event_loop.call_soon(the_task.cancel)`.

I want to ask if there is a better way to achieve the above? Is there a way I can wait on an `asyncio.Event` with a timeout somehow, similar to the `threading.Event`?

Comment: IIRC, you can build something like Curio's `timeout_after` function pretty easily for `asyncio`, but it ends up being a little heavier (because you have to wrap it in a `Future` and then `wait` that with a timeout). Anyway, with that, you can do `await timeout_after(3, self.stop_event.wait)`, which gets what you want. I can try to dig up my implementation if you're interested and can't figure it out from that hint, but probably not until tomorrow…

Comment: I found the source and will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Is there a way I can wait on an `asyncio.Event` with a timeout somehow, similar to the `threading.Event`?

[`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) supports conveniently adding timeouts to any awaited coroutine. An emulation of the timeout feature of `threading.Event.wait` for `asyncio.Event` could look like this:

```
async def event_wait(evt, timeout):
    # suppress TimeoutError because we'll return False in case of timeout
    with contextlib.suppress(asyncio.TimeoutError):
        await asyncio.wait_for(evt.wait(), timeout)
    return evt.is_set()
```

This allows a `run` almost exactly like the one that used `threading.Event`:

```
async def run(self):
    while not await event_wait(self.stop_event, 3):
        pass  # do stuff
```

Comment: @IvanKalchev Thanks. I considered creating a Python pull request that adds the optional timeout to `asyncio.Event.wait`, but then I noticed that the timeout is [intentionally left out](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html), with the documentation explicitly pointing to `asyncio.wait_for`. So this answer is pretty much the way it's intended to be done.

Comment: Do you happen to know why a separate method is used for this?

Comment: @IvanKalchev I think the idea was that those _timeout_ arguments all over the place are simply not **needed** in asyncio because you can just use `asyncio.wait_for` or `future.cancel`, and so on. This is not the case with threads, where timeout arguments are actually necessary because interrupting a thread is not supported (for good reasons, and not only in Python). Since asyncio is about blocking calls and waiting, pretty much every coroutine would have to support a _timeout_ argument, so the devs decided to omit all of them and provide a generic `asyncio.wait_for` instead.

Comment: @IvanKalchev I think that was a bad decision in the case of `Event`, `Condition`, etc., which were otherwise written to closely model their `threading` counterparts, but for what it's worth, the decision was intentional, it's not a mere oversight. Someone sufficiently interested in the matter should argue on the bug tracker that the _timeout_ arguments be implemented for `Event.wait` and others that have them.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am sure it's not an oversight, I just wandered why this decision was taken.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the Event class and add this functionality

```
 class AsynEventWithTimeout(asyncio.Event):
    async def wait(self, timeout: float | None = None) -> bool:
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(super().wait(), timeout=timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return False
        return True

async def event_setter(event: AsynEventWithTimeout) -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(11)
    event.set()

async def main() -> None:
    event = AsynEventWithTimeout()
    asyncio.create_task(event_setter(event))

    counter = 0
    while not await event.wait(timeout=2):
        print(f"Hello {counter}")
        counter += 1

asyncio.run(main())
```